# Ember.js - Adding a basic controller makes the model data unavailable in template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have nested routes like:

```
this.resource('collections', { path: '/collections' }, function() {
    this.resource('collection', { path: '/:collection_id' }, function() {
        this.resource('movies', { path: '/movies' }, function() {
            this.resource('moview', { path: '/:movie_id' });
        });
    });
});
```

If I create a basic route like:

```
App.MovieRoute = Em.Route.extend({

    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render({outlet: 'movies'});
    }
});
```

The route is accessed via a link-to in the movies template.

My template has access to the models attributes directly:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="movie">
    {{movieName}}
</script>
```

But if I add a basic controller:

```
App.MovieController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
});
```

and add setupController to the model:
    App.MovieRoute = Em.Route.extend({

```
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render({outlet: 'movies'});
    },

    setupController: function(controller, model) {
    }
});
```

I no longer have access to the variable movieName in the template (it is undefined).  If I add the controller and don't implement setup controller it fails with the error "undefined is not a function".  Is there something I can add to the Movie controller so that it doesn't interfere with the access to the variables in the template?  I've tried adding an init that cales super in the controller without luck:

```
App.MovieController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    init: function() {
       this._super();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Meori Oransky pointed out in his post, you overrode the default function of setupController. setupController by default will instantiate the model for the controller, so you want to ensure that you do this first.

You want your Movie Route to look like this:

```
App.MovieRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
         controller.set('model', model);
    },
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render({outlet: 'movies'});
    }
});
```

An aside, setupController allows you to have greater flexibility to what happens in the model. You're able to manipulate data, validate conditions and reroute if necessary. You can specify the controller you want to use, etc. At the bare minimum though, you need to always set the model for the controller, otherwise you will lose this hook in the templates.

Answer (score 1):

The default implementation of setupController is (the equivalent of):

```
setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set("model", model);
}
```

you have just overridden that with your empty implementation.